# Did Jupiter enter into the body of the constellation Virgo?

Tags: astronomy

There is a [claim](https://www.romancatholicman.com/revelations-12-sign-begins-day-year-mercy-ends-2/) spreading around and I'd like to know if this is correct from the astronomical side.

> On November 20, 2016, an astronomical event begins that will last nine
>   and a half months...

and then it follows:

> On November 20, 2016, Jupiter (the King planet) enters into the body
>   (womb) of the constellation Virgo (the virgin).

the next claim:

> After 9 ½ months, Jupiter exits out of the womb of Virgo. Upon
>   Jupiter’s exit (birth), on September 23, 2017, we see the
>   constellation Virgo with the sun rise directly behind it (the woman
>   clothed with the sun).

Did this happen and continue happening in the skies? Can the astronomers see this event or is this just some made up story to support their correlation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's pretty easy to check.

You can download [Stellarium](http://stellarium.org/), an easy to use, open-source planetarium software.

Launch it, search (Ctrl+F) for Jupiter, and press :

- Space to follow jupiter
- C for constellation lines
- V for constellation names
- R for constellation art
- G to disable the ground
- A to disable the atmosphere
- Ctrl+M for equatorial mount, so that the view doesn't rotate with the Earth anymore.
- You can either press F5 to input a time, press L multiple times for fast forward or press J multiple times for rewind.
- This way, you can follow Jupiter's path as seen from Earth in 2016 and 2017. You'll notice it is in Virgo, but only along her left arm. Jupiter doesn't come closer to her body, neither in 2016 nor in 2017.

If you look at the actual constellation of Virgo and not just the drawing superimposed over it, you will see that Jupiter was in the torso of Virgo.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, Jupiter is now in the constellation of Virgo. Not only astronomers but everyone can see it with their own eyes (unless it's cloudy or you're in a big city where you cannot see a single star). Just find the Jupiter in the sky - see, it's in Virgo.

BTW, Mercury is in the Cancer now, Mars (with the Sun) in Gemini, Venus in Taurus and other planets in other constellations.

In case you cannot see the sky or do not know where which constellations is - use [The Planets Today](http://www.theplanetstoday.com/the_planets.html) website to see in which constellation which planet is.

Comment: Will it also be there until September 23, 2017?

Comment: @Grasper When I look at that site, I get this: "Jupiter in Libra. Jupiter enters Scorpio at Tue Oct 10 2017 06:20
GMT-0700 (PDT)"

Comment: I think the part of the claim that might warrant skepticism is that this is a nine month event, therefore telling a pregnancy/birth story. *"After 9 ½ months, Jupiter exits out of the womb of Virgo."*

Comment: Perhaps "Jupiter in Libra" means Jupiter is is the sign of Libra, which (because of the precession of the equinoxes) no longer coincides with the constellation of Libra.